# Assigning matrix to struct

Tags: c

Basically I'm trying to assign the matrix elements to an array of structs. First struct to have a=1, b=2, c=3, second one a=4, b=5, c=6 and so on. My problem right now is that I can't figure it out how to do in the `setmat` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COLS 3
#define MAX_ENTRIES 3

typedef struct str_t_ {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} str_t;

void setmat(str_t *str, int mat[][COLS]) {
    str->a = mat[][0];
    str->b = mat[][1];
    str->c = mat[][2];
}

void printmat(str_t str[MAX_ENTRIES]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ENTRIES; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n\n", str[i].a, str[i].b, str[i].c);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int matrix[][COLS] = {
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            { 4, 5, 6 },
            { 7, 8, 9 }
    };
    typedef str_t str_;
    str_ *structs[MAX_ENTRIES];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ENTRIES; i++) {
        setmat(&structs[i], matrix);
    }
    printmat(structs);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the definition of `setmat` to take a pointer to a row of the matrix:

```
void setmat(str_t *str, int row[COLS]) {
    str->a = row[0];
    str->b = row[1];
    str->c = row[2];
}
```

There is another problem in your `main` function: `structs` is not an array of `str_t`, it is defined as an array of pointers to `str_t`. Furthermore, it is bad style and unnecessary to define types with local scope.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int main(void) {
    int matrix[][COLS] = {
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            { 4, 5, 6 },
            { 7, 8, 9 }
    };
    str_t structs[MAX_ENTRIES];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ENTRIES; i++) {
        setmat(&structs[i], matrix[i]);
    }
    printmat(structs);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. And i understand what i did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up copying a 2d array with copying one row of a 2d array.
A version copying the 2d-array could look like:

```
void setmat(str_t *str, int mat[][COLS]) {
    for(i = 0;i < MAX_ENTRIES;i++)  {
        str->a = mat[i][0];
        str->b = mat[i][1];
        str->c = mat[i][2];
        str++;
    }
}
```

and the call should be:

```
setmat(structs, matrix);
```